# How do I specify class name as variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to do something like this:

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = 0
}

let results = realm.objects(Dog)
```

...but specify the object name as a variable.

This doesn't work:

```
let objectName = "Dog"
let results = realm.objects(objectName)
```

Neither does this:

```
let object = Dog
let results = realm.objects(object)
```

...or this:

```
let object = Dog()
let results = realm.objects(object)
```

...or this:

```
let object: Dog
let results = realm.objects(object)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the type directly with `Dog.self`:

```
let type = Dog.self
```

I don't have a project with realm, but in theory you should then be able to do something like:

```
let results = realm.objects(type)
```