# Defining Instances of 'Cell' Inside of If Statements - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to be able to change the definition of my cell to read off different custom cell classes. I have tried referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447786/swift-set-custom-uitableviewcell-class-inside-if-statement) and reading the chat, but to no avail. Here is my code for defining the cell variable

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DiscussionTableViewCell else {fatalError("Unable to create cell")}
```

I also referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915093/how-do-i-specify-class-name-as-variable-in-swift) to potentially have a variable equal the class that is changing using this code

```
let customCell = DiscussionTableViewCell.self
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? customCell else {fatalError("Unable to create cell")}
```

However I get an error 'Use of undeclared type 'customCell''. I don't mind if the solution is changing a variable to refer to the right class or just have the change inside an if statement, but no solutions have tried actually worked. It would be nice if I could simply do something like this:

```
    if (singlePageVar == 2) {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DiscussionTableViewCell else {fatalError("Unable to create cell")}
        cell.discussionTitleLabel.text = discussionTitles[indexPath.row]
        cell.discussionDescriptionLabel.text = discussionDescriptions[indexPath.row]
    }
    if (singlePageVar == 25) {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DiscussionTableViewCell else {fatalError("Unable to create cell")}
        //assign different things here
    }
    return cell
```

but no matter how I define cell above this code such as let cell: UITableViewCell and then change it in the if statement there is always the same error.

Comment: Have you created class of customCell ?

Comment: In the last example, what about putting a `return` in each `if`?

Comment: Why didn't you use the solution presented in the first linked post? The second link is rather irrelevant.

Comment: All solutions didn't work, and the tableView that all this is in needs a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same custom cell type but different content create the cell before the first `if` statement.

And force downcast the cell, it has the same effect as the `guard / fatalError` syntax.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DiscussionTableViewCell

if singlePageVar == 2 {
    cell.discussionTitleLabel.text = discussionTitles[indexPath.row]
    cell.discussionDescriptionLabel.text = discussionDescriptions[indexPath.row]
}
else if singlePageVar == 25 {
    //assign different things here
}
return cell
```

---

However if you have different cell types you have to create and return the cells separately

```
if (singlePageVar == 2) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DiscussionTableViewCell        cell.discussionTitleLabel.text = discussionTitles[indexPath.row]
    cell.discussionDescriptionLabel.text = discussionDescriptions[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
else if (singlePageVar == 25) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherTableViewCellelse
    //assign different things here
    return cell
}
return UITableViewCell()
```

---

And once again:

## You are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as datasource.

Comment: I don't have the same custom cell type. I need to be able to assign different classes after the as! based on the singlePageVar number

Comment: Then you have to put the `let cell` and `return cell` into each `if - else` scope separately. You cannot cast the type to a variable like `DiscussionTableViewCell.self`

Comment: thank you @vadian we should really start a chat so I don't have to ask all these questions on the forum!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DiscussionTableViewCell  
if (singlePageVar == 2) {
        cell.discussionTitleLabel.text = discussionTitles[indexPath.row]
        cell.discussionDescriptionLabel.text = discussionDescriptions[indexPath.row]
    }
    if (singlePageVar == 25) {
        //assign different things here
    }
    return cell
```